# GPUImageWriter intermittent crash

Tags: gpuimage

I am using the GPUImage framework to record videos.  However, while recording, I like to be able to stop recording, start recording, and repeat.  My code is as follow:

```
-(void) startRecording {
NSLog(@"begin recording ");
dispatch_async(recordingQ, ^{
    @autoreleasepool {
        _assetURL = [self mediaURLAsVideo:YES];
        _movieWriter = [[GPUImageMovieWriter alloc] initWithMovieURL:[self mediaURLAsVideo:YES] size:CGSizeMake(640, 480)];
        [_overlay addTarget:_movieWriter];
        [_movieWriter startRecording];
    }
});
```

}

```
-(void) stopRecording {
NSLog(@"stop recording");
dispatch_sync(recordingQ, ^{
    [_overlay removeTarget:_movieWriter];
    [_movieWriter finishRecording];
});
}
```

Occasionally, I see this crash:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[GPUImageMovieWriter createDataFBO], /Users/.../Pods/GPUImage/framework/Source/iOS/GPUImageMovieWriter.m:548
```

I am not sure why this is the case but any help would be appreciated.

There's a second issue to this as well.  Occasionally, the console logs

```
Couldn't write a frame
Couldn't write a frame
Couldn't write a frame
Couldn't write a frame
```

Comment: can you get the solution ? I have same issue..